# Tail events being limsup of a sequence of events

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is almost a duplicate of [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119067/tail-sigma-algebra-and-limsup-of-a-sequence-of-subsets), which answers I do not understand so I'm asking again.

Let $\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,\dots$ be a sequence of sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Just to be sure the definitions align, we define the tail $\sigma$-algebra as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{T} := \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \sigma(\mathcal{F}_n,\mathcal{F}_{n+1},\dots) = \bigcap_{n \geq 1}\sigma\left(\bigcup_{k \geq n}\mathcal{F}_k\right)
\end{align}
$$

I want to disprove the following claim:

> For any $\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{T}$, there exists  $A_1 \in \mathcal{F_1}, A_2 \in \mathcal{F_2},\dots$ such that $\limsup{A_n} = B$

As quoted from GEdgar:

> (1). is not right. We could take $\mathcal{F}_n$ finite sigma-algebras (consisting of finite unions of intervals) such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}_n$ contains all intervals with rational endpoints, so $\sigma(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}_n)$ is the Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$, so $\bigcap_p\sigma(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}_n)) = \mathcal{B}$. But there are elements in $\mathcal{B}$ that are more complicated than limsups of finite unions of intervals.

How does his example disprove the claim? What exactly are the "more complicated" elements in the Borel set which can't be the limsup of any sequence of events?